# Zweideutige Possessivpronomen?

Tags: possessive-pronoun

In diesen Sätzen ist nicht eindeutig was passiert:

> Erich, der Dieb, und Hans sind in der Kneipe. Erich nimmt seinen Mantel und geht.

Wem gehört eigentlich der Mantel, Erich oder Hans? In einigen anderen Sprachen würde man hier verschiedene Possessivpronomen verwenden um zu markieren, wer der Besitzer ist. Kann man das im Deutschen auch oder muss man dies umschreiben, z.B. "seinen eigenen" verwenden?

Comment: In diesem Beispiel ist es in der Tat nicht eindeutig, aber es gibt mehrere Optionen. Möchte man festhalten, dass es nicht sein eigener Mantel ist, kann man z. B. _dessen_ verwenden. Man kann auch den Namen des Besitzers noch einmal wiederholen ("Erich nimmt Hans' Mantel.")

Comment: @Ingmar: Warum machst Du daraus keine Antwort?

Comment: Wie bereits erwähnt wurde, ist schon der erste Satz sehr leicht falsch zu verstehen. Also ob Erich der Dieb ist, oder ob der Dieb eine dritte Person ist. Daher würde ich den ersten Satz, je nachdem was gemeint ist, folgendermaßen umstellen: Entweder `Erich, Hans und der Dieb` oder `Hans und Erich, der Dieb`.

Comment: Lassen wir uns ihn nur "Dieb-Erich" nennen ;) Oder: " Erich und Hans sind in der Kneipe. Erich, der ein Dieb ist, nimmt sienen Mantel und geht". Meine Frage geht ja aber nicht darum ob da eine dritte Person angewesen war oder nicht, sondern um die Pronomina. "Dessen" wäre ein Alternativ, geht aber wohl mit einer Hauptzatz, wie hier nicht, oder?

Comment: Klare Sache. Der Mantel gehört natürlich dem Dieb. Zumindest am Ende der Story.

Comment: Reine Neugierde: welche Sprachen würden die Doppeldeutigkeit durch verschiedene Possessivpronomen auflösen?

Comment: Auf schwedisch wäre hier keine Möglichkeit zu einem Missverständnis. Wir verwenden hier wenn der Gegenstand dem Subjekt gehört eine "reflexive" Form vom Possesivpronomen (sin/sitt/sina) und wenn der Gegenstand einem anderen gehört das Possesivpronomen (hans/hennes/dess). Dasselbe gilt für Norwegisch und Dänisch, soweit ich weiß.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Du hast recht, der Satz ist zweideutig.

Vorher sollte aber kurz erwähnt werden, dass zumindest der erste Teilsatz (schriftlich) klar ist: Wäre der Dieb eine dritte Person, dürfte zwischen dem *Dieb* und *und* kein Komma stehen (§ 72 Rechtschreibregeln). Folglich muss Erich der Dieb sein, und wir haben es nur mit zwei Personen zu tun, was die Analyse doch deutlich erleichtert.

Ohne weiteren Kontext kann nicht entschieden werden, wessen Mantel Erich mitnimmt, wenn er geht. *Seinen* kann sich sowohl auf *ihn*, Erich, beziehen als auch auf *ihn*, Hans. Man kann die Zweideutigkeit durch andere oder zusätzliche Wörter auflösen, was im Beispiel aber nicht geschehen ist:

- > Erich nimmt *dessen* Mantel und geht.

  Hier ist klar, dass der Mantel nicht Erich gehört, also Hans gehören muss (andere Personen stehen nicht zur Auswahl).
- > Erich nimmt seinen *eigenen* Mantel und geht.

  Hier ist wiederum klar, dass es Erichs Mantel ist, denn es ist sein eigener.
- > Erich nimmt *Hans’* Mantel und geht.

  Indem der Name des Besitzers genannt wird, ist jegliche Zweideutigkeit aufgehoben.

Answer (score 7):

Es hängt im Beispielsatz nur am Komman, dass "der Dieb" ein Einschub ist und nicht eine dritte Person, deshalb ist die Ausgangssituation bei flüchtigem Lesen schon nicht ideal. Ich ignoriere jetzt einmal Einschub. (Erich und Hans..)

"Seinen Mantel" würde ich (ohne zusätzliche Hinweise) als seinen eigenen interpretieren; sollte der von Hans gemeint sein, würde ich eher "dessen Mantel" schreiben.

Comment: *der Dieb* ist hier ein Einschub, der sich auf Erich beziehen muss, da er durch Komma vom *und* getrennt ist (wobei man das mit einer weiteren Person wieder zweideutig bekommt *Erich, der Dieb, Steffen und Hans*. Dann wäre *dessen* aber nicht mehr nutzbar, da ja mehrere Besitzer zur Auswahl stünden und man müsste den Besitzer direkt benennen *Hans' Mantel/Erichs Mantel/den Mantel des Diebes*.. ).  Ansonsten +1 für dessen als Bezug auf das Nicht-Subjekt bei zwei Personen.